# Updating jtextfield's from jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, listselectionlistener

Can someone help me with this listener?

```
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
        if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
            ListSelectionModel model = table.getSelectionModel();  
            int lead = model.getLeadSelectionIndex(); 
            displayRowValues(lead);
        }
    }
    private void displayRowValues(int rowIndex){
        String country = "";   
        Object oCountry = table.getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);  
        country += oCountry.toString();
        countryTxt.setText(country );
    }
});
```

It's supposed to send data from cell in jtable (table) into a textfield (countryTxt) when one of the row's is selected, but it works only when I click on row and not when I'm cycling trough my table with arrow key's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you comment out `e.getValueIsAdjusting()` it works.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setValueIsAdjusting(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setValueIsAdjusting%28boolean%29)

Comment: Glad I could help, you should do though what @Reimeus suggests, instead of commenting it out altogether, just return when true, see the link for an explanation

Comment: Both of method's are working, but I have another problem: when deleting all rows it trows me this exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

Comment: I use this method to delete all rows: DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
  int rc= model.getRowCount();
  for(int i = 0;i<rc;i++){
   model.removeRow(0);
  }

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with this line:

```
if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
```

Replace this with:

```
if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;
```

This is a check for multiple selection events BTW.